# Restrict User To Enter Integers?

Tags: c

Hello I Want To Ask A Question About That How i Restrict User From Enter Integers And Enter Only String OR Characters.

If You Know The Answer Can You Fit That In My Code Below that Would be great if you do that btw forget the date part its just other thing.

```
void checkin()
{
char comp_choice,more_choice,in_comp_choice;
int comp_amount;
int date_month[] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
int date_month1[] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
int charges_per_room_per_day = 5000,bill;
struct info user;
system("cls");
printf("\t\tCHECK IN FORM\n");
printf("Please Fill Following Information\n");
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("checkin.txt","a");
time_t t;
time(&t);
    printf("First Name : ");
    fflush(stdin);
 gets(user.first_name);
 printf("Last Name : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(user.last_name);
 fflush(stdin);
printf("Contact Number : ");
gets(user.contact_no);
fflush(stdin);
printf("\nGuests : ");
scanf("%d",&user.guest);
printf("Rooms : ");
scanf("%d",&user.rooms);
fprintf(fp,"%s %s %s %d %d\n",user.first_name,user.last_name,user.contact_no,user.guest,user.rooms);
Label2:
printf("Today date and time is %s\n",ctime(&t));
printf("Check In  date (DD-MM-YYYY) : ");
scanf("%d %d %d",&user.date,&user.month,&user.year);
printf("Check out  date (DD-MM-YYYY) : ");
scanf("%d %d %d",&user.date1,&user.month1,&user.year1);
```

[This Is Image of i am entering Integers And Program Doesn't Say Any Thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O5Vw.png)

Comment: Calling `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: `gets()` is evil, use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: i remove fflush(stdin) but nothing happens same thing is going input integers

Comment: Not a [mcve], we don't have the definition of `struct user`, where is the main and the function is not even finish with a `}`. And worst your code is unreadable. And Why Do You Put A Upper Case In Every Word?

Comment: Stargateur i have do all things but i dont post full code in this because it is more than 1000 lines dont worry about that i have problem in this code only that i given

Comment: @alikhan I'm tired to explain basic all time. Read [mcve], please. We **NEED** the definition of `struct user`.

Comment: There is no Standard C/POSIX function to read letters only. You need to read what the user inputs, parse it, and let *your* code decide whether the input is valid. And if it's not start over.

Comment: To distinguish between letters and numbers have a look a the `is*()` family of functions (eg. `isalpha()`, `isdigit()`, ...).

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line,  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: never trust the user input.  Always validate each field, for instance if the input is a month, then validate it to be in the range 1...12 inclusive.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions:  always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code contains several unused local variables.  Your compiler should have told you about them.  Why is there a `month[]` and a `month1[]` both of which have exactly the same data?   What happens on leap year when february contains 29 days?

Answer (score 1):

A way to enforce a user entering a valid integer is to read in whatever the user enters (e.g. into a `char[..]`-buffer), and then to interpret/check the result as required. For this check, you can then either write your custom logic, or use the logic of built in functions, like, for example, `strol`.

The following sample makes use of `strtol`. The signature of `strtol` is `long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base)`. Basically, after a successful scan, `endptr` will point to the first character of `nptr` after the (successfully) scanned number; if we do not accept any characters after a (valid) number, we check if `endptr` actually points to string terminator `'\0'`; in the case of an unsuccessful scan, `endptr` is equal to `nptr`.

Here you go:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int enterIntegerValue(const char *message) {
    char inputBuffer[21];
    char *endOfScan;
    bool error;
    int result;
    do {
        printf("%s", message);
        scanf("%20s", inputBuffer);
        result = (int)strtol(inputBuffer,&endOfScan,10);
        error = (endOfScan == inputBuffer) || (*endOfScan != '\0');
        if (error)
            printf("Invalid number. Please enter a valid integer number.");
    }
    while (error);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int rooms = enterIntegerValue("Rooms : ");
    printf("input: %d", rooms);
    return 0;
}
```